# UIimageViewcontroller

Tags: iphone, uiimageview

In my view i have ImageView.If i click ,it should open nextview.

Please help in this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

override

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

method of your UIImageView (UIView, actually, but UIImageView is a subclass of UIView). This will handle UIImageView touches, so when user taps on this UIImageView, this method will be invoked.

In this method you should show next view with

```
[self.delegate.navigationController pushViewController:expenseListViewController animated:YES];
```

if you are subclassing your view controller from UINavigationController, or

```
[self.delegate presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

If you are sublclassing if from UIViewController.

Your_UIImageView delegate should be set to UIViewController object.